# Why is order important in moving from tab to tab programmatically (and new in 1.8.10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Up until I updated to jquery-ui-1.8.10 (already using jQuery 1.5), the following code has worked as expected:

```
case 'baseeditor': 
 $('#tab1').html(responseText).fadeIn(500, function() { 
  ... load the contents of the tab and stuff...
 }); 
 $("#prolearn").tabs("select",1); 
 break;
case ...
```

The tab is fueled and then focus is moved from tab0 (from where the ajax call is initiated) to tab1.

Now, that code won't work, but this version does:

```
case 'baseeditor': 
 $("#prolearn").tabs("select",1); 
 $('#tab1').html(responseText).fadeIn(500, function() { 
  ... load the contents of the tab and stuff...
 }); 
 break;
case ...
```

Can someone explain the difference - have I just been lucky getting away with my original version?

### Thanks/Bruce

Answer (score 0):

A couple of days after I posted this, jQueryUI 1.8.11 was released.  Using this version, the order of the $("#prolearn").tabs("select",1); line was not important.  So, for me, my original question has now only academic interest, but pragmatically, it is closed.